# Correct URL for Fulcrum photos in Carto Builder Pop-ups?

Tags: carto, html-popup

Does anyone know what format the source URL needs to be in for Carto Builder so that pop-ups can display images from a Fulcrum dataset? This worked before Builder was enabled in my account:

Answer (score 1):

In order to add an image to BUILDER pop-up follow these steps:

1. First, check that you have a column with url pointing to your images, such as this one: `http://i.imgur.com/ouvVPlX.jpg`. Notice that these urls should be public.
2. Click on the layer > click on POP-UP.
3. Select HOVER or CLICK pop-up.
4. Choose the last pop-up template ("IMAGE").
5. Activate the images column.

[Here](https://carto.com/blog/add-pop-ups-to.your-carto-builder-maps/) you have a blog post about adding pop-ups to your maps in BUILDER.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but I am trying to have photos display in a popup on a Carto map generated from a dataset from Fulcrum. In the older version of Carto, one was able to add images into the infoWindow through the UI. In the new Carto Builder it seems this must be done through the HTML. Unfortunately, the images are failing to display with the older code. Are there any examples of doing this with Carto Builder? I've tried several times, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read "photos". I have edited my response. Basically it is the same workflow than in the old UI.

Comment: If you think this has answered your question, please mark it as so. In doing so others users can see this is the correct answer.

Comment: It should work, but it is giving a "non-valid picture url" message in every pop-up. The URLs should be valid. Here is one from the dataset: https://web.fulcrumapp.com/shares/f3312827f670e644/photos/view?photos=914f8bbe-7e00-4467-88a6-35730136b09d                                   Is there something that needs to be done in the HTML? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You are using the wrong URL, if you right click on the image, and click on "Open image in a new tab", you get this url: https://web.fulcrumapp.com/shares/f3312827f670e644/photos/914f8bbe-7e00-4467-88a6-35730136b09d This is the right URL to use in your CARTO column.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize Carto will not take the Fulcrum-generated URL from the datashare file. I guess this means I will have to manually edit the dataset. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Sorry but this is a Fulcrum-related question. I recommend sending this question to Fulcrum support.

Comment: In case anyone is following this thread, I was in contact with Fulcrum and you can add a calculation field to a survey app that will create a public URL using something like this: SETRESULT('https://web.fulcrumapp.com/shares/{data-share-id}/photos/' + $photos[0].photo_id + '/thumbnail.jpg')

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is following this thread, I was in contact with Fulcrum and you can add a calculation field to a survey app that will create a public URL using something like this: SETRESULT('https://web.fulcrumapp.com/shares/{data-share-id}/photos/' + $photos[0].photo_id + '/thumbnail.jpg')